# gartrip calibration file format/generation

Tags: language-agnostic

I need to generate calibration files* for the [Gartrip](http://www.gartrip.com/) program. Does anyone known where I can find the file format it uses or, better yet, code for generating them?

I'm not to picky on the language.

If no one point me at anything better, I'm working on getting some examples to reverse engineer. Shouldn't be to bad as I have reason to expect them to be text.

Edit:

What I need is to be able to generate is the files need to tell gartrip: "for file *xyz.jpg*, point *A* is at location *B*, point *C* is at location *D*"

*calibration files tell gartrip how to use image files as background so that tracks and whatnot can be overladed on it

Comment: Do you mean route files as in "Calibration" files? In that case, [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) can convert between a gazillion formats.

Answer (score 0):

I've made search for [Gartrip](http://www.gartrip.com/) related entries in your [blog](http://arrayboundserror.blogspot.com/search?q=gartrip) but were in vain.

One possibility is to reverse engineer the calibration file's format and write an utility based on  knowldedge extracted.

Gartrip seems to be a proprietary software so as a registered user are you entitled to do so?

The only thing I am sure of is that it's author doesn't disclose any file format.

Comment: As it happens, I'm not a registered user and I wasn't ultimately trying to *read* any data, so (aside from issues like the DMCA) I don't I was under any legal constraints.